# Parent & Child Tables Unique ID Field

Tags: mysql

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've have a form which allows the user to save information to the following table:

**Parent Table**

```
   CREATE TABLE `finds` (
  `userid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `locationid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `findid` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `findosgb36lat` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `findosgb36lon` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `dateoftrip` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `findcategory` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `findname` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `finddescription` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `detectorid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `searchheadid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `detectorsettings` varchar(600) default NULL,
  `pasref` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `findimage` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `additionalcomments` varchar(600) default NULL,
  `makepublic` varchar(3) NOT NULL default 'no',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`findid`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Part of the form will involve the saving of images where the information provided by the user will populate the following table.

**Child Table**

```
    CREATE TABLE `images` (
      `imageid` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `userid` int(6) NOT NULL,
      `locationid` int(6) NOT NULL,
      `findid` int(6) NOT NULL,
      `filepath` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`imageid`),
      KEY `findid` (`findid`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB 

DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The field which links the two is 'findid'. Could someone tell me please is there a way of creating the record in the parent table and hence the allocation of the unique 'findid' value, whilst, simultaneously copying that same unique 'findid' value to the child table, so that I can link the records.

Many thanks and kind regards

**Form**

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST"> 
 Photo: <input type="file" name="photo"><br> 
 <input type="submit" value="Add"> 
 </form>
```

Save PHP

```
<?php 

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "images2/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("host","user","password") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Writes the information to the database 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('$pic')") ; 

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying to my post. I've added the image form and save PHP script to my original post which will hopefully give a bit more information on what I'm trying to achieve. The problem I'm having is not saving the files, but I'm just not sure, perhaps because I'm new to this, how I can link the parent and child records when the unique 'findid' hasn't been created in the parent table. Kind regards

Comment: always take time in question... half problem is solved there only... Reader has to understand question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you're asking, but if you are asking how to insert into one table, get the auto incremented ID from that table, then turn right around and use it in a query for the next table, then look at the PHP function [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to grab that value in between the two `INSERT` queries.

Comment: Hi, many thnaks for this. Having read a little more about this, I think that this will work. Kind regards